# VPN troubles on Galaxy S8

Tags: vpn, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have an ipsec/l2tp VPN server setup on a debian box back home, and it works very well. I can use it any time from any where on both my laptop and my ipad. But when it comes to my S8, it doesn't work for some reason. I've deleted and reconfigured it countless times, and I've tried looking through logs with a terminal emulator. It just seems to time out on the connection every time. I've also tried to use other VPN apps to connect to my server and they all have the same issue. What could this be?

Thanks,
Emanuel

Comment: Do you connect your S8 and your iPad via Wifi and/or via mobile network?

Comment: I use both wifi and LTE on both of them. The ipad doesn't seem to care. My phone works on neither of them.